# I'm finding "Object Layout library" on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm searching "Object Layout library" its working on JavaScript.
I want to implement function for my web app like these feature below (look at this link).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUmBD.jpg

I already searched information but I couldn't find a good module. Do you know a library something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you are looking for [interact.js](https://interactjs.io/) here is [the npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/interactjs).

Read the docs to learn, see the snippet bellow to see if is that what you want.

```js
function dragMoveListener(event) {
    var target = event.target
    // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
    var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx
    var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
        target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)'

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
}

window.onload = () => {
    interact('.resize-drag')
        .resizable({
            // resize from all edges and corners
            edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true },
            listeners: {
                move(event) {
                    var target = event.target
                    var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0)
                    var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0)

                    // update the element's style
                    target.style.width = event.rect.width + 'px'
                    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px'

                    // translate when resizing from top or left edges
                    x += event.deltaRect.left
                    y += event.deltaRect.top

                    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
                        'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)'

                    target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
                    target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
                    target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '\u00D7' + Math.round(event.rect.height)
                }
            },
            modifiers: [
                // keep the edges inside the parent
                interact.modifiers.restrictEdges({
                    outer: 'parent'
                }),

                // minimum size
                interact.modifiers.restrictSize({
                    min: { width: 100, height: 50 }
                })
            ],

            inertia: true
        })
        .draggable({
            listeners: {
                // call this function on every dragmove event
                move: dragMoveListener,

                // call this function on every dragend event
                end(event) {
                    var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p')

                    textEl && (textEl.textContent =
                        'moved a distance of ' +
                        (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.pageX - event.x0, 2) +
                            Math.pow(event.pageY - event.y0, 2) | 0))
                            .toFixed(2) + 'px')
                }
            },
            inertia: true,
            modifiers: [
                interact.modifiers.restrictRect({
                    restriction: 'parent',
                    endOnly: true
                })
            ]
        })

}
```

```css
.resize-drag {
  background-color: #29e;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  touch-action: none;

  width: 120px;

  /* This makes things *much* easier */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs/dist/interact.min.js"></script>
<div class="resize-drag">
    Resize from any edge or corner
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I understood how to implement these objects! It's awsome!